# Adjust UICollectionView Size Dynamically to Ensure No Inter Item Spacing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

The goal is to have a UICollectionView with a specific number of columns per row, regardless of the size of the screen.

Currently I am using:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    //print(collectionView.frame.size.width)
    let numberRows:CGFloat = 7
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/numberRows, height: collectionView.frame.size.width/numberRows)
}
```

To set the size of the cells so that they can fit inside the collection view without inter item spacing. However, the size of the collection view is set based on a percentage of the screen size. If the desired "numberRows" does not divide evenly, then there will be spacing between the cells.

How can I dynamically change the collection view size to ensure the cells will fit without spacing? How can this be accomplished in a more efficient way?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I am having the same issue and didn't find an answer yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the size of your collection view, you could round it down to a multiple of numberRows. This ensures it will divide evenly.

If you are using AutoLayout, you could set the width or height constraints of the collection view. Then call `layoutSubviews:` or `setNeedsLayout`

If you are not using AutoLayout, you can change the size of the collection view using `setFrame` or `setBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can not break the mathematical rules here. If you get one point/pixel to much you can not break this pixel into two half-pixels.

What you can do is:

- size the collection view accordingly so that the number of cells fit perfectly
- accept that one of the cells will have one pixel more/less size then the others. (e.g. the last cell in the row)